# Functional Dependency Clarification

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, functional-dependencies

I am in the process of creating a database for a final project (elementary school) and was a bit confused if I was getting my functional dependencies correctly.

Here are a few tables:

[image: ERD]

[image: erd2]

Here are my derived functional dependents:

**Schools Table:**
School_ID -> School_Name, School_Year

**Subjects Table:**
Subjects, School ID -> School Year, Subject Name

**Course_Join_Periods Table:** 
Course_Period_ID , Course_ID , Grade_Level_ID, Teacher_ID, Grade_Level, School_Year, Grade_Name, Period_ID, School_ID, Subject_ID, Subject_Name -> Period_Class_Name

Do I have anything correct here or should I go back to the drawing board and re-teach myself F.D's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determining the FDs is part of analysis, not design.  The FDs you have stated could be correct at your elementary school but incorrect or incomplete at mine.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but your comment cleared me of a huge misconception! Thanks!